# How to add tar command to backup script

Tags: linux, command, tar

I am trying to add a tar command to the /test/backup/backup.sh that creates a full backup of everything in my file system except the /text directory to a file called /test/backup.dat.  Plus redirect the standard output from this command to a file called /test/backuplog.txt.  Redirect the standard error from this command to a file called /test/errlog.txt. How would I get this done? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that by adding this at the end of each command

```
<command> >>/test/backuplog.txt 2>>/test/errlog.txt
```

also you need to make sure that `/test/backuplog.txt` and `/test/errlog.txt` is writable

Comment: I do not quite understand this. Please elaborate. Thank you.